# Is there any connection between the Bartimaeus trilogy and Lockwood and Co.?

Tags: bartimaeus, lockwood-and-co

The Bartimaeus trilogy and *Lockwood and Co.* are both written by Jonathan Stroud.

They have some distinct thematic similarities and similar elements.

- There are spirits in both, although they are rather different between the series.
- The spirits in Bartimaeus come from the “Other Place,” whereas those in Lockwood and Co. come from the “Other Side.”
- The theme of a spirit being able to possess a body plays a prominent role.
- The description of ectoplasm in Lockwood and Co. sounds *veeeery* similar to the description of essence in Bartimaeus.
- Notably, in both series iron and silver are inimical to essence/spirit.
- Even more notably: despite it being canonical in Lockwood and Co. that the Source of a spirit is some leftover body part, the final book features a spirit bound to a bracelet made of *jade*—*the same material as the Amulet of Samarkand*, which bound a strong spirit in the Bartimaeus sequence.

Now they can’t precisely be set in the same world, since they’re in essence inconsistent, but some of these similarities seem like a little more than just coincidence.

Is this just an author retreading similar themes, or is there some connection between the worlds of these series? Has Stroud commented on this at all?